# Agave Nectar vs Candi Syrup

Tags: belgian

I'm looking to brew a Belgium Tripel but using all American ingredients, specifically from the Southwestern United States.

Would Agave Nectar impart a different flavor than using a Belgium Candi Syrup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it will.  Probably not bad, but different.

Answer (score 1):

I have used maple syrup when making Belgian style beer - which was nice but gave a different result to Candi syrup. Not a great difference and definitely not a bad difference, but it was detectable. Perhaps a bit more caramel?